# DOTWeen и перемещение камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня движется камера, с помощью этого кода: (где playerTransf этот объект движется с помощью rigidbody.velocity):

```
LateUpdate()
{
   if (!isDOTWeenControl)
   {
      Vector3 pos = playerTransf.position;

      pos.x += 5f;

      camTransf.position = pos;
   }
}
```

В конце уровня мне нужно немного "довести" камеру до позиции, с помощью DOTWeen DOMoveX, и вот когда камера уже управляться с помощью DOTWeen, то объекты которые управлялись с помощью rigidbody(они внизу и на них смотрит камера, а также они движутся через AddForce) начинают дрожать как это исправить?

Comment: Как связаны объекты и камера? Их движение должно быть независимо.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Когда камера движется через DOTWeen объекты начинают дрожать)